# Which langages let you use fully customised lexems, including keywords and all symbol defined in their grammar?

Tags: unicode, programming-languages, customization, grammar, lexer

I wish to code fully with Esperanto lexemes. That is, not ending up with a English/Esperanto mix up. [Perligata](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~damian/papers/HTML/Perligata.html/) is a good example of the kind of result I would like, but it use Latin where I want to use Esperanto.

So Perl seems to be a valid answer to my question. On the other end a language like Python have no mechanism that would let you use *se* (*if* in esperanto) rather than *if*. On what you may call middle ground, you have languages like C that allow to replace keywords through its processor (`#define se if`), but won't allow you to get ride of the *define* keywords itself. Also you have languages like [racket](http://racket-lang.org/) and the LISP-family that would probably let you use wrap most internal symbols, but probably not allow you to easily change parentheses for anything else. For example mapping `(` with `ene` and `)` with `ele`.

Also an other point is ability to use unicode in identifiers, as Esperanto do use non-ASCII characters in its alphabet, like *ĉ*. That's not really a blocking element, as one is available to use *cx* instead of *ĉ*, but its nevertheless an interesting parameter.

So I guess an ideal answer to this question would be a matrix of languages specifying their lexeme and grammar customability.

Answer (score 0):

each formal language has its syntax. in my opinion, lowest 'syntax overhead' is offered by lisp-like languages. but then you don't want to have parenthesis. you also don't want to have `#define` therefore you reject any syntax at all and all possible replacements.
i don't think there is any language that will let you do it. you should look for language generators, write your own language (at least the syntax part) or the simplest possible way, add your own find-replace layer on top of any existing language